# adding a card as an item of carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a slider for my card component. but the problem is I am not able to display them in a proper manner.

I tried setting the width of `Carousel inner` from `100%` to `25%` but That increases the number of pages in the carousel and shows blank pages when data from my API runs out.

providing the link for codesandbox [Here is the link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-grass-15yook?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your link didn't work for me `DependencyNotFoundError
Could not find dependency: '@fontsource/roboto' relative to '/src/App.js'`

Comment: Also, far better to add the compiled html/js/css here in your question as a snippet

Comment: I removed that dependency from the code now you can try running it

Comment: Your issue is this. You have 8 cards and 8 buttons. Each card is 25% of the width. When you click on the 2nd card you are offsetting the view by (2-1)*50%.. For the 8th card you are doing (8-1)*50% = 350%. However, your total percentage is 4*25% = 200%. You need to decide on what your functionality should do.

Comment: You probably don't want a button for each card, you probably want a button for each "page" (4 cards)

Comment: yes you got it absolutely correct, but I exactly don't know how to create the page consisting only 4 cards, as my map method of card is rendering all the data from api